# Send file from javascript to blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I use `Summernote` as my text editor. I want to save images in my API directory. So when I get the file in JavaScript file how can I send it to `Blazor` (I don't want to send it via `jQuery` ajax to API directly).

```js
window.JsFunctions = {
    LoadSummerNote: function (dotNetObject) {
        $('.summerText').summernote({
            height: 300,
            minHeight: 100,
            maxHeight: null,
            focus: false,
            callbacks: {
                onImageUpload: function (files) {
                    //data = files[0]
                    data = new FormData();
                    data.append("file", files[0]);
                    dotNetObject.invokeMethodAsync('UploadEditorImage', data)
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My problem is in the `Blazor` section, that I can't get the file to continue what I want to do.

```cs
[JSInvokable]
public async Task UploadEditorImage(IBrowserFile file)
{
    // ...
    // var result = await UploadService.Upload(file, allowedExtensions, maxFileSize, uploadFolder);
    // ...
}
```

I get an error like this

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: System.NotSupportedException:
> Deserialization of interface types is not supported. Type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.IBrowserFile'. Path: $ |
> LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.  --->
> System.NotSupportedException: Deserialization of interface types is
> not supported. Type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.IBrowserFile'.

Comment: The error is telling you that it doesn't know how to deserialize an interface (since how would it know which object you wanted constructed, I guess). Have you tried with a concrete type?

Comment: The documentation is quite detailed, see https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: @Nikki9696 Yes, I tried but I received it null .

Comment: @Matze It's not related to my question. My question is different from usual upload.

Answer (score 0):

So...
you are creating a FormData object called "data" and appending the File to it.

> `data = new FormData();`
>
> `data.append("file", files[0]);`

you are then passing the "data" object to the C# method in Blazor

> dotNetObject.invokeMethodAsync('UploadEditorImage', data)

The C# method in Blazor is expecting a object that has implements the IBrowserFile interface type to be passed to it... which is what is failing...

> public async Task UploadEditorImage(IBrowserFile file)

assuming (files) is a string array of files

> onImageUpload: function (files)

The easiest way around this, considering you have the FilePath maybe something like this...
Where you pass the array of File Paths to the dotNet Method.

```
window.JsFunctions = {
    LoadSummerNote: function (dotNetObject) {
        $('.summerText').summernote({
            height: 300,
            minHeight: 100,
            maxHeight: null,
            focus: false,
            callbacks: {
                onImageUpload: function (files) {
                    dotNetObject.invokeMethodAsync('UploadEditorImage', files)
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and then handle the array of files in the dotNet Method.

```
[JSInvokable]
public async Task UploadEditorImage(string[] files)
{
  foreach (string file in files)
  {
    // ...
    // var result = await UploadService.Upload(file, allowedExtensions, maxFileSize, uploadFolder);
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: As a side note... this may also be of interest.. 

A basic wrapper for Summernote, that you can use to embed into Blazor Pages..
https://github.com/BlazingComponents/Summernote

It will serialize any images put into the Summernote content window as Base64 Strings along with all the formatting etc. 

[BlazingComponents - Summernote Example][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClNSm.png